# Compare List of Sentences and List of words and return complete Sentences , if word is present

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk, list-comprehension

From the List of Sentences and List of words, how to return the list of complete Sentences , if a word is present.  Please suggest.   Below are example lists.

```
listwords = ['people',  'Covid-19',  'Lockdowns', 'Maximum' ]

listsent = ['The number of people suffering acute hunger could almost double.',
        'It is potentially catastrophic for millions',
        'Lockdowns and global economic recession have',
        'one more shock – like Covid-19 – to push them over the edge',
        'people must collectively act now to mitigate the impact']
```

'people' is present in two sentences, 'Covid-19' present in one sentences and 'Lockdown' in one sentence.
**output list should have these four matching complete sentences from listsent.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension is a quick way to do this:

```
[sentence for sentence in listsent if any(word in sentence for word in listwords)]
```